# Splunk - Charting average transaction duration (Y-axis) over host (X-axis)

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am using Splunk to chart the average duration of a transaction, for each host, refer to the search query below

```
(host = "A" OR host = "B" OR host = "C" OR host = "D" OR host = "E" OR host = "F" OR host = "G" OR host = "H") 
AND source = "logs/BAU.log"

| transaction submission_id startswith="ABC Logic begins" endswith="ABC Logic ended"

| chart avg(duration) by host
```

I now have a chart with avg(duration) in seconds as the Y-axis, host as the X-axis.

[image: my splunk chart]

How do I change `avg(duration)` so that it's expressed in decimal minutes (something like 2.34 mins) instead of the current seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `avg(duration)` to minutes in your Splunk query using `eval`.

Here's the code :

```
(host = "A" OR host = "B" OR host = "C" OR host = "D" OR host = "E" OR host = "F" OR host = "G" OR host = "H") AND source = "logs/BAU.log"
| transaction submission_id startswith="ABC Logic begins" endswith="ABC Logic ended"
| eval duration=duration/60 
| chart avg(duration) by host
```

Hope my answer will help.

Comment: as a follow-up question, do you happen to know how to adjust the decimal places of `duration`? i would like to limit it to 2 decimal places because one of the duration values is coming up as `2.1333333`

Comment: you can use ````round```` function, here's an example instead of 
````eval duration=duration/60```` 
do
````eval duration=round(duration/60, 2) ````

Comment: hi @Iliasse, i have another question related to Splunk, if you can assist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76684706/splunk-group-x-axis-elements-together thanks in advance

Comment: someone already answered the question ;)